# How to inherit paths from CMakeLists in parent directories?

Tags: cmake, makefile, cmakelists-options

I have two projects `PROJ` in my workspace `ws` with corresponding third party libraries `TPL` as shown below. All depend on opencv 4.4.

```
ws   
├── PROJ1 (opencv 4.4)
|    └── TPL1 (opencv 4.4)  
└── PROJ2 (opencv 4.4)
    └── TPL2 (opencv 4.4)
```

`PROJ1`, `PROJ2` and `TPL1` have following lines in their `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})
find_package(OpenCV 4.4 REQUIRED)
```

Whereas `TPL2` only have:

```
find_package(OpenCV 4.4 REQUIRED)
```

but does not have

```
set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})
```

When I run `cmake` and `make` inside `PROJ1/build` and `PROJ2/build` they succeessbully get built. However, notice that `PROJ2` gets built without `TPL2` having `set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})` specified in its `CMakeLists.txt`, but `TPL1` needs to have this line for `PROJ1` to build successfully. Otherwise it gives following error:

```
fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
26 | #include <opencv/cv.h>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is it so? Is there some `CMakeLists.txt` config that lets third party apps to inherit paths from `CMakeLists.txt` in parent directories or something similar?

PS: I do not do `make install` in any of these `PROJ`s and `TPL`s.

Comment: "Is there some `CMakeLists.txt` config that lets third party apps to inherit paths from `CMakeLists.txt` in parent directories or something similar?" - What "paths" you are talking about? Variables like `OpenCV_DIR` are inherited from the parent's `CMakeLists.txt` automatically. But those variables should be used by the inner project. E.g. by `find_package` (and following `target_link_libraries`), or by `target_include_directories`, or by some other means. Please, provide **more code** of your projects (preferably in a form of [mcve]). Currently provided code and error message are vague.

Comment: Ok I edited question to make it more clear. Both `TPL1` and `TPL2` CMakeLists.txt have `find_package(OpenCV 4.4 REQUIRED) `. But, `TPL1` needs to specify `set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})` in its CMakeLists.txt for it to build successfully, whereas `TPL2` gets build successfully without needing to have `set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})` in its CMakeLists.txt. Somehow `TPL1` is unable to inherit `set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})` from its parent's `CMakeLists.txt` but `TPL2` is able to inherit it from its parent's `CMakeLists.txt`. Why this might be happening?

Comment: "Why this might be happening?" - Without viewing the **code**, we could only speculate about possible reasons. It could be that variable `OpenCV_DIR` is modified by some other code in your project (you could use [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) command for debug such situation). Or it could be that `TPL2` project is included into `PROJ2` via `add_subdirectory` command, and that command is issued **before** setting the variable (`set(OpenCV_DIR $ENV{OPENCV4_DIR})`).